# angular2-datagrid property 'id' doesn't exist in type string

Tags: angular, typescript, datagrid

I'm trying to implement angular2-datagrid followig [this tutorial](https://jmvtrinidad.github.io/angular2-datagrid/#/home)

My model:

```
export class Inventory{
    active: boolean;
    constructor(public id: number,
        public article: string,
        public description: string,
        public quantity: number,
        public price : string,
        public imgURL: string,
        public createdAt: string,
        public updatedAt: string) {
            this.active = true;
    }
}
```

My component specifically in ngOnInit:

```
this.getAllInventory();
this.table = new NgDataGridModel<Inventory>([]);
for (let inv in this.allInventories) {
    this.table.items.push(new Inventory(
        inv.id,
        inv.article, 
        inv.description, 
        inv.quantity, 
        inv.price, 
        inv.imgURL, 
        inv.createdAt, 
        inv.updatedAt)
    );
}
```

this.getAllInventory() is a method what call a web servcice and fill the allInventories in the for loop.

Here the method:

```
getAllInventory(){
    this.inventoryService.getAllInventory().subscribe(
    data=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.allInventories = data;
    },
    err=>{
        alert ("Error getting inventories");
        console.error(err);
    }
    );
}
```

Here the method who call a service, this method returns a json array of inventories:

```
getAllInventory(){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.globalVar.getToken()}`);
    var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    var result = this.http
       .get(this.globalVar.getHost() + "inventory", options)
       .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    return result;
```

}

My error: inside de for loop, the object inv in its atributes, tell me: property 'id' doesn't exist in type string, and the same with all atributes. How can I fix it??

Comment: Can you share your `getAllInventory()` method? It's probably returning `string`

Comment: I putted in the question @echonax :D

Comment: Where do you initialize `this.allInventories`? Is your code even working? You won't be having the response from `getAllInventory` before the for loop. There's an async issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the type of each property inside Inventory used in Angular 2 model does not match with that of the server data.

Two options

1. Modify the model same as in the web service.
2. Use the below code and cast the properties

   getAllInventory(){
       this.inventoryService.getAllInventory().subscribe(
       data=>{
           console.log(data);
           let tempInventory : Inventory

   ```
       data.forEach((item) => {
           tempInventory=new Inventory();

           tempInventory.id: _.toInteger(item.id),
           tempInventory.article: item.article.toString(),
           tempInventory.description: item.description.toString(),
           tempInventory.quantity: _.toInteger(item.quantity),
           tempInventory.price : item.price.toString(),
           tempInventory.imgURL: item.imgURL.toString(),
           tempInventory.createdAt: item.createdAt.toString(),
           tempInventory.updatedAt: item.updatedAt.toString() 


           this.allInventories.push(tempInventory);
       }) 
   console.log(this.allInventories);
   },
   err=>{
       alert ("Error getting inventories");
       console.error(err);
   });
   }
   ```

Comment: Your second option looks good, but I got this error: Can not read property push of undefined. I think is because the async process

Comment: Might be. Where are to making this call? On Init?